# Is it possible to "import" a Saints Row 2 character into SR3?

Tags: saints-row-the-third, saints-row-2

*I realize I could answer this for myself by spending an hour or two with [Image as Designed](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Image_as_Designed) and the [Initiation Station](http://www.saintsrow.com/community/characters), but I'm hoping someone already has the answer.*

While there isn't any way to directly import characters from Saints Row 2 into Saints Row: The Third, the character customization for both games is very similar.  But are they similar enough?  Would using the same values for each customization parameter produce the same face?  Do they even have all the same parameters?

Comment: To clarify, you don't mean actually importing; you want to create a SR3 character exactly like your SR2 character?

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis — Exactly.

Comment: That's what I thought. I've edited the title to match: as always, feel free to roll back or edit if you feel it's needed.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis - even though your title is probably more accurate, I found it made the question much more obtuse. I think, in this case at least, the original title better reflects the underlying intent of the question.

Comment: @RavenDreamer, that's fine. I'm very familiar with SR2 and am a programmer anyway, so I'm not at all the best judge of what makes sense to a wider audience.

Comment: You could take a picture of your Saints Row 2 character, and try to make it close as you can its what I did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After spending some time in Image as Designed in SR2 and in the SR3 Initiation Station, it's clear that you **cannot** create the same character in both games by using the same values.

While both games share nearly all the same customization sliders, the values are relative, not absolute.  This can be most easily seen by switching ethnicities within the same game.  Even with the same skin tone and all sliders set to 50 (the default), characters will not look the same if they were created from different ethnicities because different "bases" underlie your customizations.

Similarly, SR2 and SR3 use different bases, even for the same ethnicities.  While it might be possible to create the same face in both games, they won't have the same customization values, making it impossible to easily "port" characters.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research on this, as I was curious as well. It took me about 2 hours in the creator last night, but I was finally able to make someone who looks (mostly) like my SR2 character. The changing of all the values is kind of frustrating. :/